# Show items in specific parts of a table when manipulating the DOM via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, each

This will definately be easy for you guys but it is spinning my head around and I've lost sight of what I'm doing. I should also point out that I'm really new to Javascript and the patern of the code confuses me.

So... I want to have a table that looks like the following, inside a modal that I'm creating using data from an API I have made (from an msSQL Database):

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <th class="col-12" colspan="2">Academic Routes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="preQual_Academic">
        //Only include the rows that have the "preQualTypeId = 1"
    </tr>
</table>

<table style="width:100%;" id="preQual_Access">
    <tr id="preQual_Access">
        <th colspan="2">Access Routes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="preQual_Access">
        //Only include the rows that have the "preQualTypeId = 2"
    </tr>
</table>
```

To to this, I'm loading the JSON data from the API call and then "appending" to the tables inside the "modal-body". Here is my javascript:

```
<script>
$.get(url + qualId, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $('#preQual_Academic').append(
            '<tr><td class="col-8">'
            + item.qualification + " | Level " + item.level
            + '</td><td class="col-4">'
            + '<input type="checkbox" ' + 'value="' + item.isAlternative + '"></input>'
            + '</td></tr>');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see, at the moment I'm only passing all of the data to the one table and there is no filtering/conditional iteration taking place.

**My question is... how do I write the javascript to only put the items that meet the first condition (preQualTypeId = 1) in the first table (id="preQual_Academic") and then the other items (where preQualTypeId = 2) the second table (id="preQual_Access").**

Note: I'm designing the rest of the application using ASP.Net Core using Razor Pages.

Here's the output from the API get request, just so you can see the what I'm working with and where "preQualTypeID" is coming from:

```
[{"qual_Main":14,"preQual_Sub":2,"qualificationID":14,"main_Qual":"Degree","main_Level":6,"qualification":"A Levels","level":3,"lmsLink":null,"preQualTypeID":1,"preQualType_Option":"Academic","isAlternative":false},{"qual_Main":14,"preQual_Sub":32,"qualificationID":14,"main_Qual":"Degree","main_Level":6,"qualification":"Higher National Certificate","level":4,"lmsLink":null,"preQualTypeID":2,"preQualType_Option":"Access","isAlternative":true},]
```

**UPDATE TO INCLUDE ANSWER BASED ON @paolostyle's SUGGESTION (THANKS FOR ANSWER AND COMMENTS):**

So... I ended up implemeting the "Var" rather than the "Let" as demonstrated by @paolostyle due to browser compatability as described in the comments. However, the priciple is exactly the same.

Here is my final implementation of the Javascript:

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#preQualModal').modal({
            keyboard: true,
            backdrop: "static",
            show: false,

        }).on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            var url = "/api/PreQualViewData/";
            var qualId = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id');

            $.get(url + qualId, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var tableParent = item.preQualTypeID === 1 ? $('#preQual_Academic') : $('#preQual_Access');
                    var isAltTrue = item.isAlternative === true ? '<td class="col-5 text-center"><i class="far fa-check-square"></i></td>' : '<td class="col-4"></td>';

                    tableParent.append(
                        '<tr><td class="col-7">'
                        + item.qualification + " | Level " + item.level
                        + '</td>'
                        + isAltTrue
                        + '</tr >');
                });
            });
        });

        $('#preQualModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).find('#preQual_Academic').html(''),
            $(this).find('#preQual_Access').html('')
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, once I understood that I needed to create the variable using conditional syntax, then apply that to the final append. I started getting a little bit more creative and added the...

```
var isAltTrue = item.isAlternative === true ? '<td class="col-5 text-center"><i class="far fa-check-square"></i></td>' : '<td class="col-4"></td>';
```

...bit of the code also.

Also, I followed @paolostyle's advice and changed the append to the `<tbody>` of each table rather than the `<tr>`. So the html looked like this:

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="preQualModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="preQualsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="preQualsModalLabel">
                <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                Prerequisite Qualifications
            </h3>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-12" colspan="2">Academic Routes</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="preQual_Academic">
                    @*API data goes here*@
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table style="width:100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-7">Access Courses</th>
                        <th class="col-5 text-center">Alternative route</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="preQual_Access">
                    @*API data goes here*@
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps someone as lacking in knowledge as me when it comes to Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just determine where to append the row inside the function passed to `.each`, e.g. like this:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    // assuming you only have two possible values for preQualTypeID
    let rowParent = item.preQualTypeID === 1 ? $('#preQual_Academic') : $('#preQual_Access');
    rowParent.append(/* ... */);
});
```

Sidenote - you probably don't want to append `tr`s inside a `tr`, `preQual_Academic` and `preQual_Access` should probably be a `tbody`.

---

If you had more cases to handle, you can use either `switch` or a couple of `if` statements:

```
let rowParent;  // you can also assign here the "default" value
switch (item.preQualTypeId) {
  case 1:
    rowParent = $('#preQual_Academic');
  break;
  case 2:
    // ...
  break;
  case 3:
    // ...
  break;
  // ...
}

// OR

let rowParent; // you can also assign here the "default" value
if (item.preQualTypeID === 1) {
  rowParent = $('#preQual_Academic');
} else if (item.preQualTypeID === 2) {
  // ...
} else if (item.preQualTypeID === 3) {
  // ...
}
```

Like I mentioned in the comment above, you could also do `let rowParent = $('#preQual_Academic');` and then skip the first if/switch case.

Comment: Thank you @paolostyle, much appreciated. I’ll give that a go now. It was the “let” function that I didn’t know about. I can see how this would be used in a none Boolean instance too. I will post my final implementation and mark as solution as soon as I have it working.

Comment: Oh, `let` is simply a block scoped `var` (`var`s are function scoped). Nothing fancy here, in fact it could/should've been `const`. If you have to support old browsers you can replace `let` with `var` in this particular case.

Comment: Ok, now I'm slightly confused. Is "const" what I should be using? I will need to support relatively older browsers where possible. I'm going to have a go at implementing it and I'll post the result. To be honest, (apart from the fact that I didn't know about "let"), I basically couldn;t work out how to actually write it (in terms of syntax. My background is VB so I find the "function" use difficult to work out with Javascript. Thanks again.

Comment: By "old browsers" I meant older than IE11. But it really does not matter in this case. All three keywords (`var`, `const`, `let`) are used to declare a variable with some differences but like I said, here it doesn't really matter. I would encourage to read about it if you want to really understand what's going on, these are basics of the language.

Comment: Yeah cheers, I knew what you meant by older browsers, I was thinking aloud really. I will definately look into the difference between the declaration keywords. Thanks again for the help. I've added the final implementation and marked your answer as the solution. I'm going to go and put ice on the part of my head that I've been banging against the wall now ;)

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of how you would handle the `var rowParent` if the Id was more than 2 (i.e. not boolean as I've done in the example), please? Just incase I need it in the future. Or just point to the W3Shools function type I would need (assuming this is basically an `if statement` I'm thinking it would be a `select statement` if I were to use VB terminology). Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I just got to a situation where I needed the additional code you've posted and thought I should check to see if you had written anything for me, and there it was. Thanks again for taking the time. I'm starting to understand it all more and more now. Legend!